# Getting UITableViewCell with superview from Swift to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, xcode8

I'm migrating my Objective-C project to Swift 3. and I have a little issue. How can I call this Swift function from Objective-C code?
P.S: I have already imported "project_name-Swift.h" in my `.m` file.
My Swift code:

```
func findSuperViewWithClass<T>(superViewClass : T.Type) -> UIView? {

            var xsuperView : UIView! = self.superview!
            var foundSuperView : UIView!

            while (xsuperView != nil && foundSuperView == nil) {

                if xsuperView.self is T {
                    foundSuperView = xsuperView
                } else {
                    xsuperView = xsuperView.superview
                }
            }
            return foundSuperView
        }
```

My objective c code:

```
UIButton * phoneButton = (UIButton *) sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [phoneButton findSuperViewWithClass:[UITableViewCell class]];
```

and it shows ARC Semantic Issue error in objective c code in this line "phoneButton findSuperViewWithClass" like this -> No visible @interface for UIButton declares the selector 'findSuperViewWithClass'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the use of generics is what is making your Swift-to-Objective-C bridging troublesome.
Also note that parameters are part of the method name when bridged to Objective-C.
Try refactoring your Swift function to avoid generics and to have a more Swift-like signature (and avoid modifying your Objective-C code):

```
func findSuperView(class: AnyClass) -> UIView? {

    /* ... */

        if xsuperView.isKind(of: `class`) {    // you can use a reserved keyword as a parameter name as long as you refer to it using `backticks`.
            /* ... */
        }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. Thumbs up.